# Dialogue msg after clicking on save button xaf

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, xaf

I have the following case:
in some form, when the user clicks on save button -or save and new, save and close, or ok when it is a popup detail view-, the system should check a property's value, if it matches some conditions, we want to show a dialog msg that warns the user and ask if he want to continue and save or cancel. If he want to save and continue, the system should execute some function to deal with that case.

I looked for multiple links about dialogue messages such as Ways to Show a Confirmation Dialog | eXpressApp Framework | DevExpress Documentation, but all solutions are done through creating an action, and we don't need that. We need to display this dialogue msg when saving action is executed.

I also tried to use modificationsController.SaveAction.ConfirmationMessage property but I could not reach what I want.
Do you have a solution to my case?